# What do you call a person who doesn't know when to stop eating?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What do you call a person who doesn't when to stop eating? I have character who eats more than what should be healthy but isn't greedy. I need a word for his older brother to use to describe him.

Comment: voracious, insatiable, rapacious, prodigious, gluttonous...

Comment: How ‘bout just ***fat***??  Or ***a pig***??

Comment: *Why* isn't [greedy](https://www.lexico.com/definition/greedy) the right word? *Having an excessive desire or appetite for food.*

Comment: There is a technical medical term for this, but it's been years since I saw it.

Comment: There are different classes of words you can use depending on whether the cause is medical or psychological, whether it is temporary, episodic or long-term, whether the tone is supportive or derogatory, etc. What is your character’s context?

Comment: Do you want a neutral or scientific/medical term, or more of a mean, name-calling term? You mention it's the character's brother who will use the word, and siblings are known to call each other mean names.

Comment: Do you mean literally doesn’t know when to stop, as in a medical or mental condition? Or just someone who eats too much?

Answer (score 2):

[Glutton](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glutton)

> a person who regularly eats and drinks more than is needed

Answer (score 0):

Always hungry, eternally so.

Greedy is used more to mean that they are taking *from* rather than just not knowing when to stop eating. This might apply if they were not sharing the food properly.

They are likely unaware of their own condition so greed has little to do with it. They would likely be called overweight. I would focus instead on what this behavior *means* to your character or does to, or costs him in the story. The description based on that will leap out at you and your readers as well.